# "floating" block level elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am working on a website at work and the programmer I work with mentioned that you can't float a block level element. He said I needed to find a way to in essence float block level elements without actually using the float property. For example, "floating" text to the right of a side navigation bar.

I'm still considered a newbie when it comes to web design so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My question is, how do I float block level elements without actually using the "Float" property? Can it be done? Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: There is a lot of bad advice around regarding HTML and CSS. I suggest you get used to tools like jsfiddle.net where you can quickly write test cases to to verify that the advice you get is correct.

Comment: Give us a small example of the design, if you can, and preferably a piece of code that illustrates what you have tried to accomplish the task, thus far. This gives us a better idea of what it is, exactly, that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Alohci thanks for the suggestion to visit jsfiddle.net. @fireeyedboy - I will post it tomorrow. Thanks for being willing to help!

Comment: `display: inline-block;` - with no context this is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question *how do I float block level elements without actually using the "Float" property*, you can use absolute positioning in CSS:

```
#myBlockId {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100;
    top: 100;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The above would float a block `<div id="byBlockId">...</div>` above the other content (via tha `z-index`) and position it exactly at (100, 100).

Regarding what the developer has told you, I would argue that you can *only* float block-level elements. Your best bet is probably to ask the developer to clarify what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

An element that is floated gets converted/becomes a block level element (unless defined in the CSS to be inline).

So the fact the programmer you work with has said a block level element cannot be floated is telling porkies.

If however, your programmer defines (in his own head) a block level element as an element that must remain 100% width of it's containing element and this cannot be changed, things are going to start getting tricky.

Without a visual example, helping further is impossible.

Try taking a read through this smashing article from smashing magazine:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/